# weka ROC chart cannot be differentiated

Tags: java, user-interface, charts, weka

I am using knowledge flow to compare between ROC curves of different algorithm in weka GUI knowledge flow.

I have installed JFreeChart but it does not seem to have any effect.

[image]

The sample of the ROC image is here.

Firstly, i do not understand why on the right hand side there are duplicates symbols for example j48 appearing twice. 
The ROC curve is obtained by selecting image from the model performance chart.

Is there any possible way for me to extract my ROC curves to be plotted on a graph or any other clearer APIs for me to use this effectively.

Secondly, this is my knowledge flow diagram.

I am using a training and test set.

[image]